# Developing AOSP with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I'm trying to setup a development environment to do some custom modifications on the AOSP source code, and would like to use Android Studio as my IDE. After doing the necessary steps, however, Android Studio seems to not be able to recognize some of the classes and methods. Did I do something wrong? Here's a rundown of what I did:

I did the necessary preparations (dependencies, etc.) for cloning and building AOSP according to the official documentation. After that, I cloned the AOSP 7.1.1-r11 branch with repo, and then ran the following commands:

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch aosp_arm-eng
$ make
$ mmm development/tools/idegen/
$ development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
```

The make took me about an hour, running the idegen.sh took me around 5 seconds.

The idegen.sh generated an android.ipr file which I successfully imported in Android Studio. When prompted with an SDK selection, I selected openjdk 1.8.0_121 and removed all the libraries in the classpath, as indicated in the idegen readme file.

After letting Android Studio run the initial import actions, I went ahead and opened the PhoneFactory.java from the telephony framework where I want to do my modifications. Here is where I have my problem: several dozen methods are in red (cannot be resolved).

I am sure there is no problem with how I cloned AOSP, as the make passes correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 that's a problem I also fight with since I use AOSP with android-studio (and never found a solution).

Comment: I do not see where there are Android Studio instructions on https://source.android.com. My assumption would be that this is not yet supported. That being said, I do not do full firmware builds, let alone using an IDE.

Comment: I have followed the readme included with the idegen tool: [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/tools/idegen/README)

Comment: @AlexisSorokine have you tried to do the same with eclipse? I am afraid this is not yet supported for android-studio.

Comment: I tried doing the same in Eclipse, and am still getting a bunch of errors.

Comment: I configured as it is recommended and I do not see any error. Here is my screenshot: http://pasteboard.co/A6kCe5jhD.png Do you see something different?

Comment: @Yury maybe on that one class you show but whats with "AcitivityMangerService" for example ?

Comment: There are some errors that are related to wrong imports.

Comment: This is the kind of errors that I'm getting : http://pasteboard.co/3F5iyMwF9.png , and when I try to access TelephonyManager through the link (ctrl + click) I'm directed to the decompiled class file instead.

Comment: This is very strange. I do not have such behavior in my case. I checked exactly on the same line. In my case, the method is resolved and when I click on it I am redirected into the right place.

Answer (score 9):

I always use these steps without any problem at all:

https://shuhaowu.com/blog/setting_up_intellij_with_aosp_development.html

The most important parts for your problem are:

- Set the SDK with no libraries
- In the Project Structure -> Module -> Remove all of the dependencies that ends with a .jar
- As a bonus: go to the Sources tab and browse to out/target/common/R. Right click on it and click Source

In the link you can see screenshots that can make the steps easier to follow.

Comment: +Olaia these steps dont work any more for AS 3.1 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415724/developing-aosp-with-android-studio-3-1-cannot-set-sdk-without-libraries

Comment: @likejiujitsu, I have never used AS to build modules that are part of AOSP, always from terminal in order to do the source build/envsetup and the lunch.  I am still using these steps in order to open AOSP source code and navigate through it.